# Is there a CUDA equivalent of perror()?

Tags: c, error-handling, cuda, runtime-error

Is there a CUDA function for printing both a caller-supplied error message, and an error message describing the current cudaStatus (or a caller-supplied cudaStatus), a-la-[perror()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in cuda API function to do this.

This macro will do what you're describing:

```
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)
```

The usage of the above macro is simply to insert it *after* any cuda API call or any cuda kernel call.  It's recommended to insert it after *every* cuda API call and kernel call, for example:

```
cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail");
my_kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_A);
cudaCheckErrors("kernel launch fail");
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaCheckErrors("cudaDeviceSynchronize fail");
```

It prints the user-defined message (`msg`) and also decodes the cuda API error and prints the appropriate error string message:

```
Fatal error: kernel launch fail (invalid configuration argument at t128.cu:44)
*** FAILED - ABORTING
```

You may also be interested in a discussion of error-handling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).

In response to a question below, you can easily make a function-call version:

```
void cudaCheckErrors(char *msg){
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err),  __FILE__, __LINE__);
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n");
            exit(1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why a macro rather than a function call?

Comment: There's no particular reason.  You can easily make a function call version of it.  I edited the answer with an example that is created as a function instead of a macro.