# Error in kernel when using big arrays

Tags: arrays, cuda

While using a simple function to memset CUDA array, I get `invalid argument` for big arrays ( around > `pow(2,25)`).

I am running on a Tesla k40. I should have enough memory (by far) to allocate the array, and also enough capacity to throw the amount of blocks I am, however the following code exits with an error:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>

#define MAXTHREADS 1024
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/16283216/1485872
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
                exit(1);} \
        } while (0)

__global__ void mymemset(float* image, const float val, size_t N)
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/35133396/1485872
    size_t tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    while (tid < N) {
        image[tid] = val;
        tid += gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    }
}


int main()
{

    size_t total_pixels = pow(2, 26) ;
    float* d_image;
    cudaMalloc(&d_image, total_pixels*sizeof(float));
    cudaCheckErrors("Malloc");

    dim3 bsz = dim3(MAXTHREADS);
    dim3 gsz = dim3(total_pixels / bsz.x + ((total_pixels % bsz.x > 0) ? 1 : 0));
    mymemset << <gsz, bsz >> >(d_image, 1.0f, total_pixels);
    cudaCheckErrors("mymemset"); //<- error!
    cudaDeviceReset();

    }
```

The code works fine up to (and a bit more) `pow(2,25)` in `total_pixels` but fails for `pow(2,26)`.

Coincidentally this is the point where the block size `bsz` is `65536`, which seems to be an upper limit in some GPUs, but in the Tesla k40 its supposed to be `2147483647` for the `x` dimension, while `65536` for `y` and `z` (that I am not using). Any insight about the origin of this error?

Compiler flags from VS2013: **Properties->CUDA C/C++/command line**

```
# Driver API (NVCC Compilation Type is .cubin, .gpu, or .ptx)
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin"     -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -o Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"

# Runtime API (NVCC Compilation Type is hybrid object or .c file)
set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin"     -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /Zi   " -o Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"
```

Comment: What compiler flags are you using to build this?

Comment: @talonmies humm I made a sample CUDA project and I am running that. Check the edit, does that answer the question?

Comment: The compiler default target architecture is `sm_20`, you need to specify `-arch=sm_35` for the K40. Older GPU architectures have tighter restrictions on the dimensions.

Comment: @njuffa Indeed. Consider posting an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compiling for the default architecture (sm_20), which has a block size limit of 65535 each dimension of the grid. You must build for sm_35 to be able to launch  2147483647 blocks in a 1D grid.

You should also note that the kernel you are using (which I wrote), could be run with many fewer blocks than (n/blocksize) and still work correctly, and it would be [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21340927/681865) to do so.

Comment: Thanks again! This was just for curiosity and learning, in my whole code I had that flag activated. Thanks.